# Freeswitch use mod_lcr with originate api

Tags: freeswitch

Is there a way to use mod_lcr with originate command?

I want to originate a call and have mod_lcr decide which gateway should be used based on lcr rules (cost, reliability, etc).

When mod_lcr is used in the dialplan it will populate a variable ${lcr_auto_route} with the dialstring. How can I use the same logic with originate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it.

I connect to freeswitch via ESL and execute the command

`lcr 1716 default as xml`

where 1716 is the digit sequence and default is the profile name (you can replace default with your own profile name)

Note 'as xml' will return an XML response. The response looks like this:

```html
<result>
  <row id="1">
    <prefix>1716</prefix>
    <carrier_name>carrier1</carrier_name>
    <rate>0.15000</rate>
    <codec></codec>
    <cid></cid>
    <limit></limit>
    <dialstring>[lcr_carrier=carrier1,lcr_rate=0.15000]sofia/gateway/carrier1/1716</dialstring>
    <event>
      <headers>
        <Event-Name>REQUEST_PARAMS</Event-Name>
        <Core-UUID>151c590b-cce8-4eb3-b3ae-f48bad397870</Core-UUID>
        <FreeSWITCH-Hostname>freeswitch</FreeSWITCH-Hostname>
        <FreeSWITCH-Switchname>freeswitch</FreeSWITCH-Switchname>
        <FreeSWITCH-IPv4>172.16.124.130</FreeSWITCH-IPv4>
        <FreeSWITCH-IPv6>%3A%3A1</FreeSWITCH-IPv6>
        <Event-Date-Local>2018-02-20%2007%3A33%3A42</Event-Date-Local>
        <Event-Date-GMT>Tue,%2020%20Feb%202018%2006%3A33%3A42%20GMT</Event-Date-GMT>
        <Event-Date-Timestamp>1519108422660002</Event-Date-Timestamp>
        <Event-Calling-File>mod_lcr.c</Event-Calling-File>
        <Event-Calling-Function>route_add_callback</Event-Calling-Function>
        <Event-Calling-Line-Number>633</Event-Calling-Line-Number>
        <Event-Sequence>786</Event-Sequence>
        <lcr_digits>1716</lcr_digits>
        <lcr_carrier_name>carrier1</lcr_carrier_name>
        <lcr_rate_field>0.15000</lcr_rate_field>
        <lcr_gw_prefix>sofia/gateway/carrier1/</lcr_gw_prefix>
        <lcr_lead_strip>0</lcr_lead_strip>
        <lcr_trail_strip>0</lcr_trail_strip>
      </headers>
    </event>
  </row>
  <row id="2">
    <prefix>1</prefix>
    <carrier_name>carrier2</carrier_name>
    <rate>0.12000</rate>
    <codec></codec>
    <cid></cid>
    <limit></limit>
    <dialstring>[lcr_carrier=carrier2,lcr_rate=0.12000]sofia/external/0716@proxy.carrier2.net:5060</dialstring>
    <event>
      <headers>
        <Event-Name>REQUEST_PARAMS</Event-Name>
        <Core-UUID>151c590b-cce8-4eb3-b3ae-f48bad397870</Core-UUID>
        <FreeSWITCH-Hostname>freeswitch</FreeSWITCH-Hostname>
        <FreeSWITCH-Switchname>freeswitch</FreeSWITCH-Switchname>
        <FreeSWITCH-IPv4>172.16.124.130</FreeSWITCH-IPv4>
        <FreeSWITCH-IPv6>%3A%3A1</FreeSWITCH-IPv6>
        <Event-Date-Local>2018-02-20%2007%3A33%3A42</Event-Date-Local>
        <Event-Date-GMT>Tue,%2020%20Feb%202018%2006%3A33%3A42%20GMT</Event-Date-GMT>
        <Event-Date-Timestamp>1519108422660002</Event-Date-Timestamp>
        <Event-Calling-File>mod_lcr.c</Event-Calling-File>
        <Event-Calling-Function>route_add_callback</Event-Calling-Function>
        <Event-Calling-Line-Number>633</Event-Calling-Line-Number>
        <Event-Sequence>787</Event-Sequence>
        <lcr_digits>1</lcr_digits>
        <lcr_carrier_name>carrier2</lcr_carrier_name>
        <lcr_rate_field>0.12000</lcr_rate_field>
        <lcr_gw_prefix>sofia/external/</lcr_gw_prefix>
        <lcr_gw_suffix>%40proxy.carrier2.net%3A5060</lcr_gw_suffix>
        <lcr_lead_strip>1</lcr_lead_strip>
        <lcr_trail_strip>0</lcr_trail_strip>
        <lcr_prefix>0</lcr_prefix>
      </headers>
    </event>
  </row>
</result>
```

Then I parse the XML and grab the dialstring which is in this case

```html
<dialstring>[lcr_carrier=carrier1,lcr_rate=0.15000]sofia/gateway/carrier1/1716</dialstring>
```

Then I use the dialstring (with some extra variables) in my originate command.